# converting datepicker to datetimepicker

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

In my site, using Bootstrap 4, I have a perfectly working datepicker instance giving me a calendar to choose dates. However, I want to modify this to use time as well. I've tried so many different versions of datetime pickers and put the CDN files in proper order but something is conflicting for whatever reason.

I'm hoping for someone to just point me into the direction of the best way to use a datetimepicker or just incorporate time with this, in a way that works with what I'm using now.

Here's the code for the working datepicker:

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    weekStart: 1,
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "6,0",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
});
$('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<h6>Set New Expiration: <input data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"></h6>
```

Comment: `Here's the code for the working datepicker:`. Please include the code which does _not work_ and describe what exactly the problem is.

Comment: I had another question that referenced datetimepicker code that wasn't working. I've tried multiple avenues to no avail. This is moreso to show a datepicker that I have working to see how someone with experience adding time to it could help guide it. Surely there is a javascript operation to append time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AuspeXeu DateTimePicker](https://github.com/AuspeXeu/bootstrap-datetimepicker). It also supports keyboard navigation.

```js
$(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
    format: 'm/d/yyyy',
    datesDisabled: ['2018-06-20'],
    autoclose: true
});
function showDate()
{
   console.log($('.datepicker').data("datetimepicker").getDate());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/AuspeXeu/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/AuspeXeu/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<input class="datepicker" type="text">
<button onclick="showDate()">Get Date</button>
```